# Why my 2 years old doesn't talk?

Tags: language-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At what age should I expect my daughter to talk?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/35/at-what-age-should-i-expect-my-daughter-to-talk)

My 2 years old daughter is very active and seems to learn and understand many things. She even talks a lot although what she says is meaningless.

One thing she doesn't do is uttering meaningful words. Is it normal at this age ?

Comment: Is she growing up in a multilingual environment? This could be a cause – perhaps she's speaking a language you don't understand ;)

Comment: Already asked and answered: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/35/at-what-age-should-i-expect-my-daughter-to-talk

Comment: Thanks for the link, indeed it pretty muchs responds to my question !

Comment: The question is isn't so much if it's the norm, but if it's in an acceptable range. Strangers on the internet can't answer that. Go talk to your pediatrician who then may forward you to a speech therapist.